What's the shortcut of switching between different perspectives in eclipse under KDE-Plasma on Linux?
Running Eclipse under Linux and KDE-Plasma window manager what is the shortcut to switch between perspectives, e.g between Debug and Java?
Given answers in what's the shortcut of switching between different perspectives in eclipse do not apply.
I went through the answers of what's the shortcut of switching between different perspectives in eclipse,
they do not work.
I expect to get a shortcut, in the particular given situation, which allows me to switch between perspectives, e.g Debug and Java.

In what way does that answer "not work"? It directs you on how to find what the actual keybinding is.

These answers "do not work" by not taking into account my asked for use case.
Therefore they do not answer my question.

Ctrl+F8 works for me on Plasma showing an small box in the middle of the workspace with the list of perspectives to select. F8 cycles the list while holding Ctrl key. Check possible key binding conflicts at /.metadata/.log

Ctrl + F8
Ctrl + Shif + F8
work as expected except when all panes are minimized to the side bars which seems to be a bug.
Switching can be done also with
Ctrl + 3, typing 'next p' and selecting first item in the list.
This option seems to be also affected by a workspace with minimized panes; meaning nothing will happen on ctrl+3.
Other things to check:

Check possible key binding conflicts at <workspace>/.metadata/.log
Check that those key combinations were not assigned to an application started before Eclipse. TigerVnc is such an example.

Ctrl + F8 does NOT work when there's no visible pane and randomly fails even with visible ones.

Ctrl + F8 works when there's a visible pane

Eclipse: 2024-03 (4.31.0)

Not having customized any shortcuts on my system, neither of Eclipse nor of the Window manager, the suggested Ctrl + F8 does not switch any perspective in Eclipse for me.
Stating it would is not a working solution in my use case.
My system is not customized in any relevant way.
Ctrl + 3 ... works as described, but is not a direct shortcut to my asked function.
@Collision
Yes, Ctrl + F8 collides with Window manager functionality, by default.

Have you tried changing the keybinding in Eclipse, then?

Yes. It turned out Ctrl + F8 is configured for Desktop Manager KWin - "Show Desktop Grid". This then takes precedence over Eclipse's "Next Perspective".
After I reconfigured Eclipse's keybinding (to Shift + F8) switching perspective works for me.
Thanks all for constructive feedback.

@LMC To my understanding in this thread there has not been a correct "answer" to my question, which could be upvoted. Just correct "comments", which can not be used in this way.
In other words, to my understanding "changing the keybinding" is the right answer, but this was a "comment".

@Stacko checking the key binding is mentioned in the answer: Check that those key combinations were not assigned to an application .... Changing it is obviously the action to take. Nevermind, the answer reveals an Eclipse bug and that's significant enough for me.

@LMC There were bit and pieces in "messages" which aided this conversation. Due to them this communication has lead to its outcome. To evaluate a message as a whole, to upvote or downvote it, assessing its main line of thought is relevant. Upvoting for only "a third of a message" does not exist. To me it seems the communicated main thought was "The answer is Ctrl + F8 ...", which is not correct for this use case.
